# Как передать параметр по цепочке вниз в rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Как передать параметр из map ко второму switchMap?

```
@Effect()
  navigateToTeams(): Observable<Action> {
    return this.actions$
      .pipe(
        ofTypeDeepOne<AddTeam>(
          TeamActionTypes.ADD_TEAM,
        ),        
        map(({payload: {team}}) => team.id),
        switchMap(() => {
          const richDialogRef = this.dialog.openRichContent({
            data: {
              message: 'Team has been created',
              buttonText: 'Continue to team list',
              icon: {
                name: IconNames.TRASH,
                config: {
                  size: 10,
                  colorActive: '#676767',
                  colorBase: '#676767'
                }
              },
              linkText: 'Add a user to the team ⟶'
            }
          });
          return richDialogRef.afterClosed();
        }),
        switchMap((result) => {
          const action = result.isOnButton ? new Back() : new Go({path: ['/admin/team/1232312/user']});
          return from([action, new PersistTeams()]);
          }),
      );
  }
```

Comment: какой параметр то? :) `team.id`? почему не получить его в 1м `switchMap` и `afterClosed()`  не замаппить на объект с 2мя свойствами `{ result, teamId }`?

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать forkJoin в первом switchMap  https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

UPD. Можно вот так

```js
@Effect()
  navigateToTeams(): Observable<Action> {
    return this.actions$
      .pipe(
        ofTypeDeepOne<AddTeam>(
          TeamActionTypes.ADD_TEAM,
        ),        
        map(({payload: {team}}) => team.id),
        switchMap((teamId) => {
          const richDialogRef = this.dialog.openRichContent({
            data: {
              message: 'Team has been created',
              buttonText: 'Continue to team list',
              icon: {
                name: IconNames.TRASH,
                config: {
                  size: 10,
                  colorActive: '#676767',
                  colorBase: '#676767'
                }
              },
              linkText: 'Add a user to the team ⟶'
            }
          });
          return richDialogRef.afterClosed().pipe(
            map(result => {...result, teamId})
          );
        }),
        switchMap((result) => {
          console.log(result.teamId);
          const action = result.isOnButton ? new Back() : new Go({path: ['/admin/team/1232312/user']});
          return from([action, new PersistTeams()]);
          }),
      );
  }
```

Comment: `forkJoin` не для этого используется вовсе

Comment: да, добавил еще вариант

Comment: ну ты фактически использовал мой комментарий в качестве ответа, некрасиво   Только непонятно к чему тут `forkJoin`? Приведи пример как это использовать, ссылка не является ответом на вопрос.

Comment: Думаю на счет плагиата это не совсем так. Я показал как это должно выглядеть. Да и если честно, на коммент обратил внимание только сейчас. Как использовать forkJoin? Там по ссылке во втором примере показано. Сейчас подумал, соглашусь, не лучшее решение ))

Comment: если ты про этот пример `EXAMPLE 2: OBSERVABLES COMPLETING AFTER DIFFERENT DURATIONS`, то мне не совсем понятно, как он передаст параметр, даже учитывая тот фактор что я fluent speaker в rxjs :)